# Manipulating customizer panels and fields?

Tags: theme-customizer, theme-options

I’m trying to extend WordPress customizer to include search. For this I need to manipulate panels & fields, e.g. select them, clone, add to array, etc.

The issue is that regular events do not work: panels and fields seem to load a bit unpredictably (at least for a novice like me) so I assume there is another way to attach the functionality and events.

How would one approach this?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand what the issue is... why would you need to do that for a search? Wouldn't something like this work? https://github.com/aristath/kirki/tree/3.0.0-beta.2/modules/search Using fuse.js it searches the customizer controls, shows a list of controls as you type in a textfield, and on click it focuses on the control you selected.

Comment: @Aristeides that would indeed work. How would I add to the customizer though? I’ve tried adding sections with `'type'=>'search'` and `'type'=>'kirki-search-module-section'` but it seems not to work for me

Comment: I created is as a separate plugin. You can get it from https://gist.github.com/aristath/9366f6513ae3a9d66e2926cc0d50609b and it seems to be working fine this way on my tests :)